# CSV to SQL through Python: passing multiple arguments

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv, typeerror

I am a python beginner, and I'm trying to parse a CSV file and add its contents to a database.

My current code:

```
with open('fruit.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for row in reader:
    sql = "INSERT INTO fruit(ID,NAME,COLOUR,SIZE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, [ row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3] ] )
        db.commit()
        print('done')
    except csv.Error as e:
        print('error: ' + e)
        db.rollback()
```

My current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqltest.py", line 23, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I read answers to a lot of other questions here on SE but I still can't understand how to pass several values within a row as separate values to an SQL string.

Not sure if relevant but this is the structure of the table I'm trying to write to:

```
TABLE FRUIT (
         ID int primary key NOT NULL,
          NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
          COLOUR CHAR(20),
          SIZE CHAR(20))
```

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, it'd be really appreciated!

Comment: Try putting a comma at the end of your list of lists. More, try with a tuple instead of a list of lists :)

Comment: The way I'd understood it, by leaving the ? I could pass the arguments later in the .execute() call, whereas when I tried %s (unsuccessfully) I was also trying to pass the arguments as you said. I just tried to add .format as you suggested and adjusted the rest, but I got a ProgrammingError and was told to read up about my syntax near (?, ?, ?, ?).

Comment: @Dex'ter Thanks for your reply. I assume this is what you meant? 
`sql = "INSERT INTO fruit(ID,NAME,COLOUR,SIZE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
vals = (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
cursor.execute(sql, vals)`

Comment: @Dex'ter Sorry, half comment was missing... That didn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most Python API modules, MySQL uses the `%s` operator and not `?`.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO fruit(ID, NAME, COLOUR, SIZE) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I have found this syntax in other questions but I get this result:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqltest.py", line 23, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, [ row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3] ])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'ID' for column 'ID' at row 1")`

Comment: Now that I see that, I think it's because the first line is actually the headers so it should be parsed differently. I'll see if it works if I skip that.

Comment: If first row are headers, add `next(f)` just after `with(...)` statement to skip it. Also, try casting to `int()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you clarify exactly where I'd put the `next(f)`? I can't quite make that work, sorry!

Comment: Try next line after `with()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think type error.
So, you could try below code.

use the str() function

```
cursor.execute(sql, [ str(row[0]), str(row[1]), str(row[2]), str(row[3]) ] )
```

Comment: No joy I'm afraid. I also tried leaving the row[0] as is since it's an int in the database. I think my syntax is wrong but I don't know how.